# Javascript console.log(object) vs. concatenating string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string-concatenation, pretty-print

I'm running this in node.js:

```
> x = { 'foo' : 'bar' }
{ foo: 'bar' }
> console.log(x)
{ foo: 'bar' }
undefined
> console.log("hmm: " + x)
hmm: [object Object]
undefined
```

What I don't understand is why `console.log(x)` "pretty-prints" the object, whereas string concatenation "ugly-prints" it.  And more importantly, what's the best way to make it print `hmm: { foo: 'bar' }`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The `+ x` coerces the object `x` into a string, which is just `[object Object]`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ze32g/

The pretty printing is a very nice and probably very complex underlying code that someone implemented as part of the `console` object and the `log` method.

Try this:

```
console.log("hmm: ", x);
```

Comment: I like this.  It makes me wonder why more examples don't use the `log(x, y)` form instead of `log(x + y)`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't think that the variable arguments version is as widely supported (at least Chrome and apparently node.js support it, but others may not)

Comment: `console.log("Hi %s! Have a nice day!", "John"); // Hi John! Have a nice day!`

Answer (score 20):

#### The console.log function

'console.log' is an overloaded function that accepts a list of parameters that are either passed by copy (string|number|boolean) or by reference (everything else).

In the case of values passed by copy, the value is printed by casting it as a string.
In the case of values passed by reference, the value is pretty printed as the browser sees fit.

#### The + operator

The plus sign operator (+) is overloaded. 
When both sides of the operator are numbers, the sum of the two operators is returned.

If either side of the operator is a string, then both sides will be cast as string and the concatenation of those two strings will be returned.

```
console.log("hmm: " + x);
```

is the same as writing

```
console.log(String("hmm: ") + String(x));
```

#### Solution

Prevent the implicit string casting by swapping the plus sign (+) with a comma (,)

```
console.log("hmm: ", x);
```

#### More Info

For a more in depth description of the 'console.log' function, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log

For a more in depth description on the plus sign operator (+), see:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: I would recommend linking to the MDN page on Arithmetic Operators as well (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) instead of W3Schools.

Answer (score 6):

Use `JSON.stringify` when printing an object with string appending

```
console.log("Haa"+JSON.stringify(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject));` to print your object. it work!

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options:

```
process.stdout.write('hmm: ')
console.dir(x)
```

Another...

```
var util = require('util')
process.stdout.write('hmm: ')
console.log(util.inspect(x, true, 10, true))
```

See [util.inspect](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) docs for more info.

**Edit:** Sorry, my mind thought I read Node.js. This is valid for Node.js only. So, I'll leave it for any Googlers.

**Edit2:** I'm not crazy, I just need sleep. You did write Node.js. I'm going to add it as a tag.