# Empty object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a weird situation.

I take some values from a form and save it in an object.

I print out the values and it prints fine to the console log. But when I try to access it or print again in next line. It returns empty.

Here is the code.

```
 var family = {};
    var counter = [];

    counter = document.querySelectorAll(".familyMemberBox input[name='member[]']");

    for(x=0;x<counter.length;x++){
                console.log('for loop');
                family[x] = {};

                member_number = counter[x].value;
                member_type = get_member_type(member_number);
                gender = get_gender(member_number);
                age = get_age(member_number);

                family[x]['type'] = member_type;
                family[x]['Gender'] = gender;
                family[x]['Age'] = age;
    }

    for(x=0;x<counter.length;x++){
        console.log(family[x]);
    }

            console.log('family: '+family[0]);
```

here is the console output

[image]

Comment: `console.log(family[x]);` is logging the object.  `console.log('family: '+family[0]);` is logging the _string representation of the object_, which is (unless you override it) "[object Object]"

Comment: It's just console formatting. Try: `console.log('family: '); console.log(family[0]);`

Comment: That's not an empty object, that's just a string for an object. Try `console.log("family", family[0])` instead

Comment: Try  `console.log('family: ', family[0]);` instead of  `console.log('family: '+family[0]);`

Comment: This one may explain:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597246/javascript-console-logobject-vs-concatenating-string

Comment: Whats with down voting a question. I dont understand. I spent 2 hours trying to figure out the problem before putting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it a string with this statement: `console.log('family: '+family[0]);`.

You're implicitly calling `.toString()` when you concat a string with a plain object. The string version of an object is `[object Object]`. It's not empty, don't worry.

If you're going to show the *string* version of an object, you're probably going to want to loop through and print each key and value pair, but that's probably not efficient. If you're dead set on printing `family` to the console, use a comma:

```
console.log('family: ', family[0]); // should show two individual statements, not just one coerced string
```

Comment: wow, seems like rookie mistake. Thanks for the detailed answer. I will use it in a loop. This was just to test if I was reading the values fine.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `console.log('family: '+family[0]);` is coercing `family[0]` to a string before printing.  It doesn't mean that the object is empty.

Try this instead:

```
console.log('family: ');
console.log(family[0]);
```