# How do I make an array of objects in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

My API gives me data in the following format:

```
{
  status: 200,
  certificateTypes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Gasmeting',
      created_at: '2023-04-25T07:15:55.000000Z',
      updated_at: '2023-04-25T07:15:55.000000Z',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Mangatwacht',
      created_at: '2023-04-25T07:16:13.000000Z',
      updated_at: '2023-04-25T07:16:13.000000Z',
    },
  ],
    // ...
}
```

I used the following function to put the data in an useState array.

```
const [certificateTypes, setCertificateTypes] = useState([]);

const fetchCertificateTypes = async () => {
  const response = await getCertificateTypes();

  if (response.status === 200) {
    setCertificateTypes(response.certificateTypes);
    console.log('in fetch ' + certificateTypes);
  }
};
```

Now printing the data with:

```
console.log(certificateTypes)
```

gives the following result:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

My initial thought was that I needed to JSON.parse the data I fetched, but this does not seem to be the case..

How can turn this data into an array so I can properly work with it?

Comment: your are logging using concatenation which coerces the objects to strings `console.log('in fetch ' + certificateTypes);`. You can either separate with a comma `console.log('in fetch: ', certificateTypes);` or explicitly stringify `console.log('in fetch ' + JSON.stringify(certificateTypes, null, 2));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript console.log(object) vs. concatenating string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597246/javascript-console-logobject-vs-concatenating-string)

Comment: The data is already in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to concatenate a string with an certificateTypes variable using the + operator, JavaScript automatically converts the array to a string representation, which is "[object Object]". And the **default string representation of an array is "[object Object]"**.

updating **state in ReactJS is an asynchronous process**. When you call setState() to update the state of a component, React schedules the update to occur in the future, rather than updating the state immediately. This means here when you console.log('in fetch ' + certificateTypes); **the updated state may not be immediately available after calling  setCertificateTypes(response.certificateTypes)**.

to console.log your certificateTypes, write a console.log(certificateTypes) before you return a jsx (or anywhere outside useEffect);

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your console.log to:

```
console.log('in fetch ', certificateTypes);
```